# Recurrence relation convex polyominoes of perimeter $2n+8$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, polyomino

This question concerns Exercise 4.24 from [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html).

Find a three term recurrence relation, whose coefficients are polynomials in $n$, that is satisfied by
$$
f(n) = (2n+11)4^n - 4(2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}
$$
which is the number of convex polyominoes of perimeter $2n+8$.

It seems that the answer should be:
$$
n(2n−11)f(n)=2(8n^2−42n+7)f(n−1)−8(2n−1)(2n−9)f(n−2)
$$
as written in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005436)

My question is to how one would derive this recurrence relation in a systematic way?
The $xD\log$ method described in the book does not seem to work immediately.

Comment: Hi, could you refer to a specific page with $xD$ log method? I'm not sure I understand what it refers to.

Comment: @OleksandrKulkov It is first explained on page 22 for the Bell numbers. It is also used in Exercises 1.10 and 3.7 as well as in the proof of theorem 3.10.1. Looking back at this question after a few weeks, I do think that the method will actually work after placing the generating function on a common denominator, though it seems very tedious.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhat equivalent to finding the common holonomic equation of

$$
\begin{cases}
(1-4x) \delta f(x) &=& 4xf(x), \\
(1-4x) \delta g(x) &=& 2xg(x), \\
(1-4x) \delta t(x) &=& (1+4x) t(x), \\
(1-4x) \delta h(x) &=& (1+2x) h(x).
\end{cases}
$$
where $\delta = x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, which is theoretically possible, but idk how to do it without blowing up... Reason:
$$
f(x) \sim \frac{1}{1-4x}, \\
g(x) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}, \\
t(x) \sim \delta f(x), \\
h(x) \sim \delta g(x),
$$
and the actual genfunc is $2 t(x) + 11 f(x) - 8 h(x) - 4 g(x)$.

Comment: Do they, by any chance, expect that you use some symbolic computation software rather than doing it manually?

Comment: That is certainly possible, but they do not explicitly recommend it like in Exercise 5.8. This suggests (at least for me) that the 'intended solution' of the author did not use any symbolic manipulation software.

Comment: Note that [A005436](https://oeis.org/A005436) is offset by $4$ compared to this sequence, so the actual recurrence is
$$
n(2n-11)a(n) = 2(8n^2-42n+7)a(n-1) - 8(2n-1)(2n-9)a(n-2)
$$

with the base cases $a(0)=7$ and $a(1)=28$.

I tried to find the holonomic equation programmatically, and got
$$\begin{align}
n(n-1)a(n) &= 4(n-1)(4n-5)a(n-1)\\&-12(8n^2-28n+25)a(n-2)\\&+32(4n-9)(2n-5)a(n-3)\\&-64(2n-5)(2n-7)a(n-4).
\end{align}$$

The result is puzzling, as the shorter recurrence might be due to specific base values that make it have fewer dimensions as a linear space...

Comment: Some further experimentation suggests that the shorter recurrence does _not_ seem to hold for other possible starting values or coefficients in the linear combination. So, might indeed be due to some weird degeneracy.